# Connection refused in Docker containers communicating through exposed ports

Tags: apache, docker

Hi I have a requirement of connecting three docker containers so that they can work together. I call these three containers as

- container 1 - pga (apache webserver at port 80)
- container 2 - server (apache airavata server at port 8930)
- container 3 - rabbit (RabbitMQ at port 5672)

I have started rabbitMQ as (container 3)

```
docker run -i -d --name rabbit -p 15672:15672 -t rabbitmq:3-management
```

I have started server (container 2) as

```
docker run -i -d --name server --link rabbit:rabbit --expose 8930 -t airavata_server /bin/bash
```

Now from inside server(container 2) I can access rabbit (container 3) at port 5672. When i try

`nc -zv container_3_port 5672` it says connection successful.

Till this point I am happy with the docker connection through link.
Now I have created another container pga(container 1) as

```
docker run -i -d --name pga --link server:server -p 8080:80 -t psaha4/airavata_pga /bin/bash
```

now from inside the new pga container when I am trying to access the service of server (container 2) its **saying connection refuse**.

I have verified that from inside server container service is running at 8930 port and it was exposed while creating the container but still its refusing the connection from other containers to which it is linked.

I could not find a similar situation described by anyone anywhere and also clueless how to debug the same. Please help me find out a way.

The output of command: **docker exec server lsof -i :8930**

> exec: "lsof": executable file not found in $PATH
>   Cannot run exec command fb207d2fe5b902419c31cb8466bcee4ba551b097c39a7405824c320fcc67f5e2 in container 995b86032b0421c5199eb635bd65669b1aa93f96b60da4a49328050f7048197a: [8] System error: exec: "lsof": executable file not found in $PATH
>   Error starting exec command in container fb207d2fe5b902419c31cb8466bcee4ba551b097c39a7405824c320fcc67f5e2: Cannot run exec command fb207d2fe5b902419c31cb8466bcee4ba551b097c39a7405824c320fcc67f5e2 in container 995b86032b0421c5199eb635bd65669b1aa93f96b60da4a49328050f7048197a: [8] System error: exec: "lsof": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: can you edit your question with the the output of `docker exec server lsof -i :8930`?

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Intend to expand on this but my kid's just been sick. Will address debugging issue from question when I get a chance.

You may find it easier to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for this as it lets you run them all with one command and keep the configuration under source control. An example configuration file (from [my website](https://ilikewhenit.works/blog)) looks like this:

```
database:
    build: database
    env_file:
        - database/.env
api:
    build: api
    command: /opt/server/dist/build/ILikeWhenItWorks/ILikeWhenItWorks
    env_file:
        - api/.env
    links:
        - database
    tty:
        false
    volumes:
        - /etc/ssl/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/
        - api:/opt/server/
webserver:
    build: webserver
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    links:
        - api
    volumes_from:
        - api
```

I find these files very readable and comprehensible, they essentially say exactly what they're doing. You can see how it relates to the surrounding directory structure in [my source code](https://github.com/garry-cairns/ILikeWhenItWorks).